# Installing python-igraph with pip on Mac 10.14 fails with "library not found for -lstdc++"

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph

I am trying to install `python-igraph` using `pip3` on Mac OS X 10.14, but the installation fails with the following error message:

```
$ pip3 install python-igraph

...snip...

gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/charles/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/lib -arch x86_64 -L/Users/charles/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/edgeobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/common.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/py2compat.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/graphobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/indexing.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/igraphmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/bfsiter.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/convert.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/vertexobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/random.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/edgeseqobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/error.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/vertexseqobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/arpackobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/attributes.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/filehandle.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/pyhelpers.o igraphcore/lib/libigraph.a -Ligraphcore/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lm -lstdc++ -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/igraph/_igraph.cpython-36m-darwin.so
    clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
    ld: library not found for -lstdc++
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

gcc version:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

python version:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.7
```

(Side note, `python` and `python3` point to the same python, and `pip` and `pip3` point to the same (corresponding) pip.)

I also tried running `xcode-select --install` but this told me 'command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates' (Xcode is up to date).

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
```

before running `pip install python-igraph`. Then you should see it install successfully:

```
$ pip install python-igraph
Collecting python-igraph
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/a0/4e7134f803737aa6eebb4e5250565ace0e2599659e22be7f7eba520ff017/python-igraph-0.7.1.post6.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: python-igraph
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-igraph ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/charles/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/41/d6/02/34eebae97e25f5b87d60f4c0687e00523e3f244fa41bc3f4a7
Successfully built python-igraph
Installing collected packages: python-igraph
Successfully installed python-igraph-0.7.1.post6
```